# Having problem building Android 13 for Pixel 6a

Tags: aosp, android-13

I'm trying to build Android 13 and flash it to my device, Pixel 6a.

I followed the documentation, https://source.android.com/docs/setup/start and https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building.

1. mkdir aosp
2. cd aosp
3. git config --global user.name Your Name
4. git config --global user.email you@example.com
5. repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-13.0.0_r50
6. repo sync
7. source build/envsetup.sh
8. lunch aosp_bluejay-userdebug
9. m
10. cd ~/aosp/out/target/product/bluejay (contains all imgs like boot.img, system.img)
11. adb reboot bootloader
12. fastboot flashall -w

When it finishes, it remains at fastboot screen, so I click start. I goes to Google logo, then reboots to bootloader.
My fastboot version is 33.0.1.

Does anyone know why it's rebooting to after Google logo? Is there a log that I can look at like dmesg or logcat?

Thanks